# Sensor data relationship

Tags: cross-correlation

I have data from 73 temperature sensors in form of a time series. The data looks like:

TimeStamp (minutes) Sensor1 (degrees) Sensor2 ... Sensor N

1                      25               41    -5 ...

2 ...

3 ...

4 ...

A. Is there a way I can find multidimensional (cross)correlations between different sensors, as in which sensors behave similarly at which points.

B. What could be different measures of comparison for multiple sensor time series data?

C. I am also looking to find multidimensional causalities among different sensor readings. As in change in Sensor1 caused change in Sensor2, and so on. 
[This is about the fact that Sensor 1 is located near a device which may have malfunctioned due to change in temperature at site 1, and this may cause device on site 2 to be effected.]

Is there an R package (or more) which can do these jobs?

(Machine learning approaches are desirable)